# How fix delete row in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I trying add a delete row but when im editing a some row(delete the word or symbol), the row will remove. i want delete row. if the row in editing mode and if i press a delete then the row will be remove.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Employee> johnSmith = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();[enter image description here][1]
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = johnSmith;
    }
    public class Employee
    {
        public string employeeID { get; set; }
        public string employeeName { get; set; }
        public string employeeAddress { get; set; }
        public string employeeCity { get; set; }
        public string employeeState { get; set; }
    }

    private void AddNewEmployeeClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        johnSmith.Add(new Employee()
        {
            employeeID = IDTB.Text,
            employeeAddress = AdressTB.Text,
            employeeCity = CityTB.Text,
            employeeName = NameTB.Text,
            employeeState = StateTB.Text
        });

    }
    private void datagrid_loadingrow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {


        e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex() + 1).ToString();
    }
    private void deletegrid_keydown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        {
            if (dataGrid.SelectedItem != null)
            {

                     johnSmith.Remove(item);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you please add some more context to this question?  Are you trying to delete from the dataGrid?  Are you removing something from the row object - if so, what are you trying to remove and what is the johnSmith object contain?

Comment: @RayK i want remove the row but if the row in edited mode i want the remove canceled. now when  i chang some text and press delete then the row will deleted

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent row deletion, you can use `CanUserDeleteRows="False"`.

If you want to perform some custom handling related to keyboard input, you can use `PreviewKeyDown` event and subscribe your handling method.

```
PreviewKeyDown="DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown"

private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Delete || e.Key == Key.Back)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        //put some additional handling if you need
    }
}
```